# How do you show "busy" status in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

For some of the applications on my WP7, when there is some intenses processing going on it displays the "animated dots" along the top of the screen.

I'm curious as to how to do that for my WP7 application ... any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should use the Progress Control in [Silverlight for WP7 toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291)

Comment: There are performance issues with the default one and the toolkit one is supposed to be correct.

Comment: Looks like that only works with Silverlight 4, which is what Mango supports, but not ready to go there yet.

Comment: The `PerformanceProgressBar` in the toolkit definitely supports WP7.0 / SL3. In fact, Mango has replaced the need for it by including a system progress (that appears at the top).

Comment: It's still necessary in Mango, for displaying load for async operations. But yes, the NuGet package display as it's only useable on SL4, which is a bug. (Been reported to the author)

Comment: @Claus - It's not necessary in Mango as it's primary use case has been superceded by [SystemTray.ProgressIndicator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.systemtray.progressindicator(v=VS.92).aspx])

Comment: Ah yes, but you said it like it would appear automatically. Either way, it'll be a while before we can drop pre-mango support.

Comment: Hey, useful discussion going on,i also need the same thing with something more, i want to freeze my screen for any operations and show the system tray progress bar while operation takes place. currently i am using IsEnabledChanged event and enable disable controls on the screen, any better idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use [ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx) and set [IsIndeterminate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.isindeterminate.aspx) to true.

I like this implementation of the bar as it perfroms better:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442303%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Several contributors mentioned problems in standard ProgressBar and they mostly suggested improved version called PerformanceProgressBar. A while ago I investigated various performance-related questions. Results related to the progress bar can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/WP7-Animations.aspx).

As a short summary:

- Standard progress bar has terrible perf impact as it runs in full
  speed in a privileged thread
- PerformanceProgressBar is a lot better, but not good enough. It is sufficient for cases when your app is basically waiting.
- The same conclusion concerns any animations using Storyboard.
- If you want to entertain the user while doing heavy computations,
  then the clearly best option is to organize your own animations. The
  techniques are discussed in the mentioned article.